# Отправка get на http с https

Tags: javascript, https

```
        function geo() {
          $.get("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp", function(response) {
          }, "jsonp");
        }
```

> jquery-3.2.1.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.example.ru/account/wall' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure script
>   'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?callback=jQuery32100550968950882198_1553169551733&_=1553169551734'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Пытаюсь получить название города отправляя GET на другой сервер с HTTPS на HTTP. Я понимаю, что ошибка связана с безопасностью. Вопрос в том: **можно ли это как-нибудь обойти?**

Comment: Я не эксперт в этом, но думаю, что вряд ли

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/enabling-https

Для этого установите следующий HTTP-заголовок:

Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests

Comment: Я надеюсь Вы понимаете что этот заголовок лишь включает `https`, но также у источника не может быть `https`, просто не будет работать эта ссылка